# error apache2 chmod 777 only works

Tags: apache2, chmod, vhosts, chown

I have my first server and i don't undeststand many things.
First, i've created one user called guillaume and create a specific folder in /home/web and put my website in there and it works BUT...

i've created a second website and it's work but only with chmod 777
i've made chmod -R guillaume:guillaume *
and chmod -R 777 * 
but if i do 
chmod -R 755 * 
i've an error 500, file cannot be writed...

So i don't understand why i don't change permissons to 755, on my first domain it works well.

there is my vhosts:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName bio.dev2prod.fr
 ServerAdmin guillaume.batier@gmail.com
 DocumentRoot /home/guillaume/web/bio.dev2prod.fr/public
 <Directory />
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
     Allow from all
 </Directory>

 <Directory /home/guillaume/web/bio.dev2prod.fr>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  Require all granted
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

what am i doing wrong ?
PS: i put my user to www-data group ? it that good ? 
Thanks and sorry for my bad english, i'm french..

PS: i'm using laravel 5 so the document root is in /public folder

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be caused by several issues. So let me ask a few questions.

1. (if I'm not totally wrong) the first `<Directory>` directive points to the root directory. wich might not directly relate to your problem but are you sure to map any file? I guess it should be same as `<DocumentRoot>`
2. The `<DocumentRoot>` should be the base directory for the particular vhost. So the `<Directory>` path should normaly belong to a sub directory of the DocumentRoot.
3. If you wan't to use directories from outside the DocumentRoot [`mod_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) might be worth looking at.

   `Alias /somalias/  /path/to/somewhere/else`

Hope this helps you a bit.